# Sitecore jQuery version compatibility

Tags: javascript

We are using Sitecore 7.2 Update 4, jQuery 1.9.1 and Bootstrap 3.2.2

We are using `TypeAhead` which uses Bootstrap but it's not working in our solution as it's picking up jQuery version 1.5.1 included by Sitecore which isn't compatible.

We are not in preview mode - the Sitecore toolbar is not visible.

jQuery 1.9.1 is included in the head
jQuery 1.5.1 is added by Sitecore towards the end of the body
Bootstrap is included at the end of the body

I've tried adding

```
jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

And moving jQuery 1.9.1 to the end of the body but this didn't change things.

Comment: Are you using WFFM in your solution? WFFM is loading both jQuery and Bootstrap (and a load of other scripts), and there is no way to configure that.

Answer (score 2):

There are some ideas here that you might be able to use Steve:
[Dealing with jQuery version collisions in WFFM](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/484/dealing-with-jquery-version-collisions-in-wffm)

e.g unloading jquery after testing it:

```
if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined' && jQuery.fn.jquery == "1.4.2") {
    jQuery.noConflict(true);
}
```

Or the answer I posted on the above link about using HTML Agility Pack, loading in the DOM, removing JQuery version added by Sitecore and then adding your own.